# Sokoban game won't push boxes in new level - Python - Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, maze

I am designing a sokoban clone in Python(Pygame)

The game works fine when moving 1 crate 3 positions to the right, hitting a black space, and moving you on to the next level. But in the second level, when trying to move 1 crate UP 1 position, the crate instead moves to the position 3 down and 1 to the left.

what am i missing here guys? :(

code below, or full code with media download here 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7whgt1duvlpwleb/Sokoban%204.9.zip?dl=0

-------------Main Class--------------------

```
#import classes
#from maze3 import Maze
from amaze import Maze
from crate import Crate
from Sobokan import Sobokan
"""from maze2 import Maze
from maze3 import Maze
from maze4 import Maze
from maze5 import Maze"""
#add pygame imports
import random, sys, copy, os, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
maze = Maze()
#maze2 = maze.leveltwo()
sob = Sobokan("^", 5, 1)
crate = Crate("@", 0, 0)

FPS = 30                    # frames per second to update the screen
WINWIDTH = 800              # width of the program's window, in pixels
WINHEIGHT = 800           # height in pixels
HALF_WINWIDTH = int(WINWIDTH / 2) #you need to know 1/2 sizes so you can
HALF_WINHEIGHT = int(WINHEIGHT / 2) #place things centrally
# The total width and height of each tile in pixels.
TILEWIDTH = 64
TILEHEIGHT = 64
TILEFLOORHEIGHT = 64
BRIGHTBLUE = (  0, 170, 255)
WHITE      = (255, 255, 255)
BGCOLOR = BRIGHTBLUE
#A dictionary of the images used.  You can then use#floor, wall etc
#in place of the whole pathname
IMAGESDICT = {'floor': pygame.image.load("Images/flooring.png"),
              'wall': pygame.image.load("Images/wall.png"),
              'box': pygame.image.load("Images/hoost.png"),
              'sob': pygame.image.load("Images/Sapp.gif"),
              'spacer': pygame.image.load("Images/spacer.jpg") }
TILEMAPPING = { '#':IMAGESDICT['wall'],
                ' ':IMAGESDICT['floor'],
                '@':IMAGESDICT['box'],
                '/':IMAGESDICT['spacer'],
                '^':IMAGESDICT['sob']}
pygame.init()
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINWIDTH, WINHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Sobokan v 1.00')
BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)
score = 0
def moveSobLeft():
    x = maze.getCharAtPos(sob.getRow(), sob.getCol() - 1)
    y = maze.getCharAtPos(sob.getRow(), sob.getCol() - 2)
    r = maze.getCharAtPos(sob.getRow(), sob.getCol() - 1)

    print "x/y init works"
    if x == "#":
        print "You have hit a wall, you cannot move!"
    elif x == " ":
        print "This is a space!"
        sob.moveLeft()
        maze.placeSob(sob.getChar(), sob.getRow(), sob.getCol())
        maze.clearAtPos(sob.getRow(), sob.getCol()+1)
    elif (x == "@" and y == " "):
        print "You have collided with a sprout, the sprout will move away now"
        crate.pushboxleft()
        print "crate pushed right"
        #this is pretty much the only thing that changes the blit of the crate.
        maze.placecrate("@",crate.getRow()+1, crate.getcol()-2)
        print "crate placed"
        maze.clearAtPos(crate.getRow(), crate.getcol()+1)
        print "old crate cleared"
        sob.moveLeft()
        print "Player moved right"
        maze.placeSob(sob.getChar(), sob.getRow(), sob.getCol())
        print "Player placed"
        maze.clearAtPos(sob.getRow(), sob.getCol()+1)
        print "old player cleared"
    elif (x == "@" and y == "#"):
        print "You have hit a sprout, but the sprout is trapped!"
    else:
            pass

    print maze.GetBoxes()



def moveSobRight():
    global score
    x = maze.getCharAtPos(sob.getRow(), sob.getCol() + 1)
    y = maze.getCharAtPos(sob.getRow(), sob.getCol() + 2)
    r = maze.getCharAtPos(sob.getRow(), sob.getCol() + 1)

    print "x/y init works"
    if x == "#":
        print "You have hit a wall, you cannot move!"
    elif x == " ":
        print "This is a space!"
        sob.moveRight()
        maze.placeSob(sob.getChar(), sob.getRow(), sob.getCol())
        maze.clearAtPos(sob.getRow(), sob.getCol()-1)
    elif (x == "@" and y == " "):
        print "You have collided with a sprout, the sprout will move away now"
        crate.pushboxright()
        print "crate pushed right"
        #this is pretty much the only thing that changes the blit of the crate.
        maze.placecrate("@",crate.getRow()+1, crate.getcol()+2)
        print "crate placed"
        maze.clearAtPos(crate.getRow(), crate.getcol()-1)
        print "old crate cleared"
        sob.moveRight()
        print "Player moved right"
        maze.placeSob(sob.getChar(), sob.getRow(), sob.getCol())
        print "Player placed"
        maze.clearAtPos(sob.getRow(), sob.getCol()-1)
        print "old player cleared"
    elif (x == "@" and y == "#"):
        print "You have hit a sprout, but the sprout is trapped!"
    elif (x == "@" and y == "/"):
        print "You have pushed a crate on to a diamond, free point to you!"
        crate.pushboxright()
        print "crate pushed right"
        #this is pretty much the only thing that changes the blit of the crate.
        maze.placecrate("@",crate.getRow()+1, crate.getcol()+2)
        print "crate placed"
        maze.clearAtPos(crate.getRow(), crate.getcol()-1)
        print "old crate cleared"
        sob.moveRight()
        print "Player moved right"
        maze.placeSob(sob.getChar(), sob.getRow(), sob.getCol())
        print "Player placed"
        maze.clearAtPos(sob.getRow(), sob.getCol()-1)
        print "old player cleared"
        score = score + 1
        print "Score: " +str(score)




    else:
            pass



def moveSobUp():
    print "Key up"
    c1 = crate.getRow()
    c2 = crate.getcol()

    z = sob.getCol()
    w = sob.getRow()
    x = maze.getCharAtPos(sob.getRow()-1, sob.getCol())
    y = maze.getCharAtPos(sob.getRow()-2, sob.getCol())
    print "x/y init works"
    if x == "#":
        print "You have hit a wall, you cannot move!"
    elif x == " ":
        print "This is a space!"
        sob.moveUp()
        maze.placeSob("^", w-1, z)
        print "player should be placed"
        maze.clearAtPos(w, z)
        print "player should be cleared"
    elif (x == "@" and y == " "):
        print "You have collided with a sprout, the sprout will move away now"
        #move crate
        crate.pushboxup()
        maze.clearAtPos(c1,c2)
        maze.placecrate("@",c1 - 1,c2)
        #move sob
        sob.moveUp()
        maze.clearAtPos(sob.getRow(),sob.getCol())
        maze.placeSob(sob.getChar,sob.getRow() - 1,sob.getCol())


def moveSobDown():

    #moving sob down
    #Check he can move
    x = maze.getCharAtPos(sob.getRow()+1, sob.getCol())
    y = maze.getCharAtPos(sob.getRow()+2, sob.getCol())
    print "crate row : " + str(crate.getRow)
    print "Crate Col : " + str(crate.getcol)
    if x == "#":
        print "You have hit a wall, you cannot move!"
    elif x == " ":
        print "This is a space!"
        sob.moveDown()
        maze.placeSob(sob.getChar(), sob.getRow(), sob.getCol())
        maze.clearAtPos(sob.getRow() -1, sob.getCol())
    elif (x == "@" and y == " "):
            print "This is a box!"
            #move the box first and then the man!
            crate.pushboxdown()
            sob.moveDown
            #place the crate in the maze in the new position
            maze.placecrate("@", crate.getRow()+1,crate.getcol())
            maze.placeSob(sob.getChar(),sob.getRow()+1,sob.getCol())
            maze.clearAtPos(crate.getRow() - 1,crate.getcol())


            maze.clearAtPos(sob.getRow()-1,sob.getCol())
            #then move the man
            #then place the man in the maze
            #then clear original position
            maze.pushBox()

            sob.moveDown()
            maze.clearAtPos(sob.getRow() - 1, sob.getCol())
            maze.placeSob(sob.getChar(), sob.getRow(), sob.getCol())
    print maze.toString()
    print sob.toString()
def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, IMAGESDICT, TILEMAPPING, BASICFONT, score
    maze.placeSob('^', 5,1)
    print maze.toString()
    drawMap(maze)
    while True:
                #thread 1 - look for an action
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # event handling loop
            if event.type == QUIT:
                # Player clicked the "X" at the corner of the window.
                terminate()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    moveSobRight()
                elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                    moveSobLeft()
                elif event.key == K_UP:
                    moveSobUp()
                elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                    moveSobDown()
                elif event.key == K_SPACE:
                    restart()
                else:
                    pass
            mapNeedsRedraw = True
        if score == 1:

            score = 0
            maze.leveltwo()
            maze.clearAtPos(5,1)
            maze.placeSob('^', 5,1)
            maze.clearAtPos(1,2)
            maze.placecrate('@',2,4)
            crate = Crate("@", 2, 4)
            #do i need multiple crates for .setcrate ?
            maze.placecrate("@",2,4)
            sob.setRow(5)
            sob.setCol(1)




        #thread 2: redraw the screen
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR) #draws the turquoise background
        #if something has changed, redraw....
        if mapNeedsRedraw:

                mapSurf = drawMap(maze)



                #mapsurf =
            #elif score == 3:
                #mapsurf = drawmap(maze3)
            #elif score == 4:
                #mapsurf = drawmap(maze4)
            #elif score == 5:
                #mapsurf = drawmap(maze5)

        mapNeedsRedraw = False
        mapSurfRect = mapSurf.get_rect()
        mapSurfRect.center = (HALF_WINWIDTH, HALF_WINHEIGHT)
        # Draw the map on the DISPLAYSURF object.
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(mapSurf, mapSurfRect)
        pygame.display.update() # draw DISPLAYSURF to the screen.
        FPSCLOCK.tick()
def drawMap(maze):
    #draw the tile sprites onto this surface.
    #this creates the visual map!
    mapSurfWidth = maze.getWidth() * TILEWIDTH
    mapSurfHeight = maze.getHeight() * TILEHEIGHT
    mapSurf = pygame.Surface((mapSurfWidth, mapSurfHeight))
    mapSurf.fill(BGCOLOR)
    for h in range(maze.getHeight()):
        for w in range(maze.getWidth()):
            thisTile = pygame.Rect((w * TILEWIDTH, h * TILEFLOORHEIGHT, TILEWIDTH, TILEHEIGHT))
            if maze.getCharAtPos(h, w) in TILEMAPPING:
                #checks in the TILEMAPPING directory above to see if there is a
                #matching picture, then renders it
                baseTile = TILEMAPPING[maze.getCharAtPos(h,w)]
            # Draw the tiles for the map.
            mapSurf.blit(baseTile, thisTile)
    return mapSurf
def restart():
    maze.__init__()
    sob.setRow(4)
    sob.setCol(1)
    maze.placeSob(sob.getChar(), sob.getRow(), sob.getCol())
    drawMap(maze)

def text(text,textcolour):
    smalltext = pygame.font.font('freesansbold.ttf',20)
    largetext = pygame.font.font('freesansbold.ttf',20)
    titletextsurf,titletextrect = maketextobjs(text,largetext,textcolour)
    titletextrect.center = (int(maze.getwidth / 2),int(maze.getHeight / 2))
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(titletextsurf,titletextrect)
    typtextsurf,typetextrect = maketextobjs("press key to continue",smalltext,white)
    typtextrect.center = (int(maze.getwidth/2),int(maze.getHeight/2)+75)

def terminate():
    #shutdown routine
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

-------------Maze Class-------------------------

```
class Maze:
    """2D Maze for the player to play the game in"""

    def __init__(self):
    """the maze constructor
    (none) -> none
    start by declaring attributes"""
        self.maze = [['#','#','#','#','#','#','#'],
                       ['#',' ','@',' ',' ','/','#'],
                       ['#',' ',' ','#',' ','#','#'],
                       ['#',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'],
                       ['#',' ',' ','#','',' ','#'],
                       ['#',' ',' ','#','#','#','#'],
                       ['#','#','#','#','#','#','#']]
        self.width = 7
        self.height = 7
        self.box = 1

    def toString(self):
    """prints out the maze
    (none) -> none"""
        printme = ""
        for i in range (0,len(self.maze)):
            for j in self.maze[i]:
                printme = printme + j
            printme = printme + "\n"
        return printme

    def placeSob (self, Sob_char, row, column):
    """places a Sobokan at a specified row and column in the maze
    (char, int, int) -> none
    >>>placeSob("$", 2, 2)
    NoneType"""
        self.maze[row][column] = Sob_char

    def placecrate (self, crate_char, row, column):
    """places a Sobokan at a specified row and column in the maze
    (char, int, int) -> none
    >>>placeSob("$", 2, 2)
    NoneType"""
        self.maze[row][column] = crate_char


    def clearAtPos(self, row, col):
        self.maze[row][col] = " "


    def getCharAtPos(self, row, col):
        """This is a very important method as it allows you to check for
        walls and boxes
        >>>getCharAtPos(0,0)
        '#'"""
        return self.maze[row][col]

    def pushBox(self):
            self.box -= 1

    def getWidth(self):
        return self.width

    def getHeight(self):
        return self.height
    def getCurrentMaze(self):
        return self.maze

    def leveltwo(self):
        self.maze = [['#','#','#','#','#','#','#'],
                       ['#',' ',' ',' ',' ','/','#'],
                       ['#',' ',' ',' ','@','#','#'],
                       ['#','#','',' ',' ',' ','#'],
                       ['#',' ',' ',' ','',' ','#'],
                       ['#','^',' ',' ',' ','#','#'],
                       ['#','#','#','#','#','#','#']]
        self.width = 7
        self.height = 7
        self.box = 1
        return self.maze

    def GetBoxes(self):
        return self.box
```

---------------Sokoban Class ---------------------------

```
class Sobokan:
    #add attributes for sobokan character
    def __init__(self, x, r, c):
        """Constructor for sobokan. Needs to pass in values
        for the character representing sobokan, row and column
        >>> sobokan("$", 2, 3)
        NoneType"""
        self.char = x
        self.row = r
        self.col = c
        self.box = 0
    def toString(self):
        info = "Sobokan " + self.char + " at row " + str(self.row) + " and column " + str(self.col)
        info = info +  " has pushed " + str(self.box) + " boxes today."
        return info
    def getRow(self):
        return self.row
    def getCol(self):
        return self.col
    def getChar(self):
        return self.char
    def setRow(self, r):
        self.row = r
    def setCol(self, c):
        self.col = c
    def moveRight(self):
        self.col += 1
    def moveLeft(self):
        self.col -= 1
    def moveUp(self):
        self.row -=1
    def moveDown(self):
        self.row +=1
    def pushBox(self):
        self.box += 1
    def pushboxup(self):
        self.row -= 1
    def pushboxdown(self):
        self.row += 1
    def pushboxleft(self):
        self.col -= 1
    def pushboxright(self):
        self.col += 1
```

-----------Crate Class --------------------------

```
class Crate:
    #add attributes for sobokan character
    def __init__(self, x, r, c):
        """Constructor for sobokan. Needs to pass in values
        for the character representing sobokan, row and column
        >>> crate("@", 2, 3)
        NoneType"""
        self.char = x
        self.row = r
        self.col = c
        self.box = 0
    def toString(self):
        info = "crate " + self.char + " at row " + str(self.row) + " and column " + str(self.col)
        info = info +  " has been pushed " + str(self.box) + " times today."
        return info

    def pushboxup(self):
        self.row -= 1
    def pushboxdown(self):
        self.row += 1
    def pushboxleft(self):
        self.col -= 1
    def pushboxright(self):
        self.col += 1

    def getRow(self):
        return self.row

    def getcol(self):
        return self.col

    def setCol(self, c):
        self.col = c

    def setRow(self, r):
        self.row = r
```

I'm Pretty sure the Problem is in here...(MoveSobUp)

```
def moveSobUp():
    print "Key up"
    c1 = crate.getRow()
    c2 = crate.getcol()

    z = sob.getCol()
    w = sob.getRow()
    x = maze.getCharAtPos(sob.getRow()-1, sob.getCol())
    y = maze.getCharAtPos(sob.getRow()-2, sob.getCol())
    print "x/y init works"
    if x == "#":
        print "You have hit a wall, you cannot move!"
    elif x == " ":
        print "This is a space!"
        sob.moveUp()
        maze.placeSob("^", w-1, z)
        print "player should be placed"
        maze.clearAtPos(w, z)
        print "player should be cleared"
    elif (x == "@" and y == " "):
        print "You have collided with a sprout, the sprout will move away now"
        #move crate
        crate.pushboxup()
        maze.clearAtPos(c1,c2)
        maze.placecrate("@",c1 - 1,c2)
        #move sob
        sob.moveUp()
        maze.clearAtPos(sob.getRow(),sob.getCol())
        maze.placeSob(sob.getChar,sob.getRow() - 1,sob.getCol())
```

Or in here... (Maze.leveltwo)

```
def leveltwo(self):

        self.maze = [['#','#','#','#','#','#','#'],
                       ['#',' ',' ',' ',' ','/','#'],
                       ['#',' ',' ',' ','@','#','#'],
                       ['#','#','',' ',' ',' ','#'],
                       ['#',' ',' ',' ','',' ','#'],
                       ['#','^',' ',' ',' ','#','#'],
                       ['#','#','#','#','#','#','#']]
        self.width = 7
        self.height = 7
        self.box = 1
        return self.maze
```

Comment: This is a lot of code.  Really, a huge amount.  I would be more likely to look at it if you reduced it to a more manageable size that still showed the bug you're trying to fix.

Comment: i'm pretty sure the bug is in the "Move up" method of the main class, but i cannot be certain

Comment: Try removing code until you're left with the smallest possible program that still has a bug in it.

Comment: that will break the program completely XD

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you don't understand here.  You know that you can create copies of files on your computer, right?  So that if you break your program, you can go back to the old copy?

Comment: use a lot `print` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed. Many times it helps to find unexpected values in variables.

Comment: i know, i just thought you might have a more targeted diagnosis

Comment: you should use more readable names - for example: you could use `sob.row` in place of `z` (and `sob.getRow()`), or `crate.row` in place of `c1` (and `crate.getRow()`). It is difficult to understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

I see many problems in your code.

You create `crate` in `mainloop`

```
crate = Crate("@", 2, 4)
```

but it create local variable and

```
crate.setCol(5)
crate.setRow(3)
```

change position in this local `crate`
(btw: it is wrong position - it have to be col=4, row=2)

Other functions use global `crate` with `col=0`, `row=5` because it is `crate` position at the end of first level.

if you remove

```
crate = Crate("@", 2, 4)
```

then

```
crate.setCol(5)
crate.setRow(3)
```

will change global `crate`

(or add `global crate` in `main()`)

--

There are other problems with moving elements but ... you have to find it on your own ;) You have four functions `moveSobDown`, `moveSobUp`, `moveSobLeft`, `moveSobRight` and they should be almost identical but they are not.

--

btw: you have wrong char in maze - you use `''` (empty char) but it have to be `' '` (space) so second level is drawed incorrectly and you have "invisible" walls.